# Create column with incremental counter identifying duplicate set in pandas

Tags: python, function, pandas, duplicates

I have a large df, with a subset of columns which are identical `dup_columns = ['id', 'subject','topic',  'lesson', 'time']` and some that are unique `['timestamps'].`

```
   id    subj   topic lesson  timestamp  time  dup_ind dup_group  time_diff
1   1  math    add     a   timestamp1  45sec   True   1      timestamp1-timestamp2         
2   1  math    add     a   timestamp2  45sec   True   1      timestamp1-timestamp2
3   1  math    add     a   timestamp2  30sec   False   NaN
4   1  math    add     a   timestamp3  15sec   False   NaN
5   1  math    add     b   timestamp1  0sec    True    2     timestamp1-timestamp4
6   1  math    add     b   timestamp4  0sec    True    2     timestamp1-timestamp4
7   1  math    add     b   timestamp1  45sec   True    3     timestamp1-timestamp2
8   1  math    add     b   timestamp2  45sec   True    3     timestamp1-timestamp2
```

I have a column `['is_duplicate']` identifying duplicates based on dup_columns.
I need to create another column `['dup_group']` that **uniquely identifies each duplicated set of row** by assigning it a **unique duplicate group value (1,2,3,... )**. Eventually I need this `dup_group` to compare `timestamp` values within each duplicate_group (for which I am using a .diff() method).

Here is the code I wrote:

```
df2= df1.loc[df1['is_duplicated']==True]
def dup_counter():
    for name, group in df11.groupby(dup_columns):
        df[name, df['dupsetnew']]+=1
    return df['dupsetnew']

df11.groupby(dup_columns).apply(dup_counter)
```

**Problem 1:** Function is giving me error (i'm new to Python and programming)

For calculating the difference in the timestamps I have the following code:

```
df['time_diff'] = df.loc[df.dup_indicator == 1,'event_time'].diff()
```

**Problem/question 2:** Is .diff the correct method to use for what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way. Note I have changed `df['timestamp']` to a series of integers to demonstrate the principle, but this can be adapted for `datetime` ojects.

The idea is to identify groups using `pd.factorize` on a list of tuples. Then apply both forward and backward `groupby.diff` to get the desired result.

```
df['timestamp'] = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2]

df['dup_group'] = pd.factorize(list(zip(df['id'], df['subj'], df['topic'], 
                                        df['lesson'], df['time'])))[0] + 1

df['time_diff'] = df.groupby('dup_group')['timestamp'].transform(pd.Series.diff)

df['time_diff'] = df['time_diff'].fillna(-df.groupby('dup_group')['timestamp']\
                                            .transform(pd.Series.diff, periods=-1))

#    id  subj topic lesson  timestamp   time  dup_ind  dup_group  time_diff
# 1   1  math   add      a          1  45sec     True          1        1.0
# 2   1  math   add      a          2  45sec     True          1        1.0
# 3   1  math   add      a          2  30sec    False          2        NaN
# 4   1  math   add      a          3  15sec    False          3        NaN
# 5   1  math   add      b          1   0sec     True          4        3.0
# 6   1  math   add      b          4   0sec     True          4        3.0
# 7   1  math   add      b          1  45sec     True          5        1.0
# 8   1  math   add      b          2  45sec     True          5        1.0
```

**Source data**

```
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'dup_group': {1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: 2.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 3.0, 8: 3.0},
 'dup_ind': {1: True, 2: True, 3: False, 4: False, 5: True, 6: True, 7: True, 8: True},
 'id': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 'lesson': {1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'a', 5: 'b', 6: 'b', 7: 'b', 8: 'b'},
 'subj': {1: 'math', 2: 'math', 3: 'math', 4: 'math', 5: 'math', 6: 'math', 7: 'math', 8: 'math'},
 'time': {1: '45sec', 2: '45sec', 3: '30sec', 4: '15sec', 5: '0sec', 6: '0sec', 7: '45sec', 8: '45sec'},
 'time_diff': {1: 'timestamp1-timestamp2', 2: 'timestamp1-timestamp2', 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: 'timestamp1-timestamp4', 6: 'timestamp1-timestamp4', 7: 'timestamp1-timestamp2', 8: 'timestamp1-timestamp2'},
 'timestamp': {1: 'timestamp1', 2: 'timestamp2', 3: 'timestamp2', 4: 'timestamp3', 5: 'timestamp1', 6: 'timestamp4', 7: 'timestamp1', 8: 'timestamp2'},
 'topic': {1: 'add', 2: 'add', 3: 'add', 4: 'add', 5: 'add', 6: 'add', 7: 'add', 8: 'add'}})
```

Comment: I am getting an error: ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2) in the second line of the code (pd.factorize...)

Comment: @at_ca, I added my data.. this is copied from what you posted. It does work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you also be able to explain the underlying process with the factorize and why there is a [0]+1? Also, why is there a - minus sign in front of df.groupby in the 4th line of the code?